# Stacking <p> tag contents

Tags: html, css

I have 2 paragrpahs tags with text and both have width constraint. I have width constraint because I want them to stack when browser width is adjusted.

```
  <p class="text"> Line 1. Big text. </p>
  <p class="small-text">Line 2. Small text. </p>
```

The problem I am facing right now is that first line stacks it overlaps with the second and vice-versa. I treid havign it in a div, but it didnot help. Both the lines are of different font styles. So, I cant have them in the same p tag.

JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/1rxpmx4g/1/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using position:absolute?

Answer (score 2):

You will benefit from a better understanding of `absolute` and `relative` positioning.

Very simplistically, `absolute` takes the element out of the HTML flow, and sticks it at the top left corner of the current div. (This is a little too simplistic. See the first referred article for an excellent explanation -- but this is basically correct for now.)

`relative` starts with the element in its normal position in the flow, but allows you to reposition the element up/down left/right of where it began.

`float:left` and `float:right` take the element out of the normal flow, but leave it at the left margin.

Further Reading:

http://www.webdevbydoing.com/css/whats-the-difference-between-static-relative-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: OP can also benefit from using media queries and putting the stuff they want on larger viewports in a min-width

Comment: Yes, that's a good point -- although perhaps a bit beyond where the OP seems to be at the moment. Thanks for the note, though -- food for thought.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/ -- really thorough

Comment: I am using media queries. But, this particular case comes before I hit the break point for media query.

I removed the absolute position bu tit breaks it further more. My situation is. I have a div with a background image and a form alogn with thses 2 <p> tags. When I remove absolute position, the background image disappears until the screen is made smaller.

I will post a fiddle link to entire div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbv0naba/

When the position absolute is removed is removed,it gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these five steps:

### Remove absolute positioning

Take out `position: absolute`
Absolute positioning takes elements out of the flow of elements and positions it in relation to the window rather than in relation to the other elements. This is causing your elements to stay in one place and mash on top of each other.

### Remove z-index

Take out `z-index: 100`
z-index is a kind of layering system with higher numbers being the layers on top of the lower numbers. If you need these p elements to layer on top of other elements, put them in a container div and style the container to layer on top.

### Add inline block behaviour

Add `display: inline-block`
inline-block will allow your elements to display next to each other (inline). The inside of the element is formatted as a block level box, but the element itself is treated as an inline level element. This way your p elements will sit next to each other happily.

### Change widths to ems

Having a percentage width is causing your elements to resize their width according to the browser size, rather than stacking. To get the elements to stack, but also have a width appropriate for the browser size, use ems rather than percentages. Ems will size your elements by the text size rather than the browser size and adapt to the text size that the user is reading (smaller screens will render smaller text and, hence, your elements will render smaller too).

### Clean up CSS

You need to remember to keep your code DRY (don't repeat yourself). Both your p elements have some similar properties that can be put into one block of CSS rather than repeating for each. You can use the native 'p' element: `p { styles common to all p elements }`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it. But, while the overlap is removed, the background image and rest of the things are messed up.

Answer (score -3):

It's a combination of `position:absolute` and your margins as a percentage.

Comment: This should be a comment unless you edit it and provide some explanation.  As is it's not useful as an answer.

Comment: @Dan We're not here to write code for people, only to answer questions, in that respect it is in fact an answer.

Comment: Ok but it's not a good answer.  It's not helpful and it doesn't add anything to this page.  Also you have a typo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman the above was neither a critique or request for clarification, but an answer, the question was what was causing the p tags to overlay, the answer is above.